# how to make atomic rows using function regexp_split_to_table #postgresql

Tags: postgresql

i have  a table that stores amenities of a room (wifi,tv etc) a room can have many amenities i want to make a column where every amenity will be atomic

| id | amenity_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | tv |
| 2 | wifi |
| 3 | bed |
| 4 | Smokling allowed |

current table :

| id | Another header |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Wifi,Breakfast |
| 2 | Wifi,Kitchen,Smoking allowed,Pets allowed,Heating,Washer,Essentials,Lock on bedroom door,24-hour check-in,Hangers,Hair dryer,Laptop friendly workspace |

i have tried using regexp_split_to_table but i can't make anything out from this function
any ideas?
thanks.

Comment: Split up the CSV, ok. But your exact objective is unclear. Please clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a lateral join:

```
SELECT tab.id, a.name
FROM tab
   CROSS JOIN LATERAL regexp_split_to_table(tab.amenity_name, ',') AS a(name);
```